# How can I build a comparator that sorts Strings the same way that PostgreSQL does?

Tags: java, string, postgresql, sorting

I'm writing an integration test that is passing a complex `order by` to PostgreSQL and then checking that the data comes back in the correct order.  I'm writing this integration test in Java and its `String.compareTo` method appears to sort things differently from PostgreSQLs.  I ran this on my PostgreSQL database:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('D d a A c b', ' ') ORDER BY 1;
```

It responded with this:

```
a
A
b
c
d
D
```

I then created this unit test to compare that to the way Java sorts things:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class PostgresqlSortOrderTest {

    @Test
    public void whenJavaSortsStringsThenItIsTheSameAsWhenPostgresqlSortsStrings() {
        List<String> postgresqlOrder = Lists.newArrayList("a", "A", "b", "c", "d", "D");
        Ordering<String> ordering = new Ordering<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String left, String right) {

                return left.compareTo(right);
            }
        };
        List<String> javaOrdering = ordering.sortedCopy(postgresqlOrder);
        assertEquals(postgresqlOrder, javaOrdering);
    }

}
```

This failed with this output:

```
Expected :[a, A, b, c, d, D]  //postgresql
Actual   :[A, D, a, b, c, d]  //java
```

I'm very ignorant of the terminology here.  I'd like to know the names of these different String sorts so I can communicate better.  But more importantly, how can I make Java sort like PostgreSQL does?

Comment: Java does it in ASCII order. PG seems to do it in alphabetical order with lower- and upper-case of the same letter sorted in that order (lower < upper). That's enough to write the comparator.

Comment: @DaveNewton true, but if there's a library out there that already has such a comparator, I'd rather use that than write my own.  Do you know of one?

Comment: Yep, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER, in the standard API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Late to show with an answer, but I'm afraid a simple case insensitive search isn't necessarily going to do what you want.

The keyword you want in your searches is [collation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html) (and in a wider sense [locales](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/charset.html)) and PostgreSQL relies on the underlying operating-system to provide support for this. The ordering is rarely a simple character-by-character comparison. For example, in many locales spaces are ignored (that's certainly the case in en_GB).

Also, this means you can end up with different sort orders on different platforms (depending on whether Apple or Microsoft agree with Linus as to the default ordering for your country).

There has been some discussion as to whether it would make sense to include a BSD-licenced library to provide a consistent set of orderings across platforms. However, this is a lot of work and then means you can end up with different sorting inside your database from the rest of your operating-system. While different providers disagree on how to handle this, there's no one simple solution I'm afraid.

You might want to investigate the "C" collation for "traditional" sorting. I'm afraid I can't comment on Java's handling of proper locale sorting - not my field.

Comment: +1 and just as an FYI Java handles it exactly the same way. It's locale based and there's a [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class you can use.

Comment: @BrianRoach I think I need that.  My integration test passed locally with `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`, but once it ran on our CI (of a different OS and maybe locale), it failed.  I can't figure out how to get a case insensitive collator for the default locale though.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @tieTYT - Here's the problem; you're trying to depend on two different systems' behaviors which are locale based, across platforms. You either need to manage that explicitly to where they match, or pick one end and let it do the work. If it were me and I need to do insert sorting outside the database after a query (I'm presuming that's the issue) I'd just do the sort on the Java side. There's a tutorial for using the Java collation stuff here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/collationintro.html Another option could maybe be rethinking your approach to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use comparator:`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` to sort any `Collection` of `Strings`. It is already implented in `String` class.

Look at the **Field Summary** at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Worth noting is that the `ORDER BY` in postgres is dependent on locale, just like Java. Postgres 9.3 on my machine, for example, responds `[A, D, a, b, c, d]` if you do `SELECT regexp_split_to_table('D d a A c b', ' ') ORDER BY 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comparator that matches the PostgreSQL ordering using the en_GB locale:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = (left, right) -> {
    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.UK);
    collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    return collator.compare(left.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", ""), right.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", ""));
};
```