# How to build a Python comparator that sorts strings the way PostgreSQL does?

Tags: python, postgresql, collation

This question is essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957596/how-can-i-build-a-comparator-that-sorts-strings-the-same-way-that-postgresql-doe), except on Python.

I wish to query rows from a PostgreSQL database ordered by the e-mail address column and then perform operations in Python that rely on that ordering.

The database I'm querying is using the `en_US.UTF8` collation, which with a few tests, I'm finding has some peculiar behavior with respect to the `@` symbol in the e-mail addresses:

```
mydb=> SELECT '0'  < '@';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)

mydb=> SELECT '0'  < '@0';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20870199/70170) suggests that an `@` symbol may be ignored by some collations, but if that were the case here, I'd have expected a `t` from the second query.

Although Python supplies a [locale module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/locale.html), that module has [inconsistent behavior on some platforms](https://bugs.python.org/issue23195), so I seem to be unable to use that module for this purpose.

Based on that report, I tried the recommendation to use the [PyICU package](https://pypi.org/project/PyICU/), which seemed promising:

```
>>> import icu
>>> collator = icu.Collator.createInstance()
>>> collator.getLocale()
<Locale: en_US>
>>> collator.getSortKey('0') < collator.getSortKey('@')
False
>>> collator.getSortKey('0') < collator.getSortKey('@0')
False
```

But as you can see, in the last comparison, it's yielding a different order than postgres does.

I've tried specifying a different collation for the query, something like:

```
SELECT email COLLATE posix FROM mytable ORDER by email;
```

But that results in an error: `collation "posix" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist`. I tried also a collation of `"en-us-x-icu"`, but that also does not exist.

Is there any way to reliably query a column of e-mail addresses from PostgreSQL in an order upon which a Python program could rely, either by adapting the collation of the query or by honoring the default collation in Python?

Comment: Could you sort them in Python?

Comment: If it's the same but in Python, have you tried converting the answer with an implementation to Python? What happened?

Comment: I can't sort them in Python without significant performance degradation. There are millions of rows in multiple databases that would have to be loaded into memory. I do want to rely on the sort order optimizations afforded by the database.

Comment: The Java answers were largely Java-specific, although the accepted answers turn out to be the same - use the "C" collation. I had tried "posix" without success, so had not held hope that "C" would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collate "C"` in Postgres:

```
with test(test) as (
values ('@'), ('@0'), ('0')
)

select test
from test
order by test collate "C"

 test 
------
 0
 @
 @0
(3 rows)
```

Python:

```
>>> test = ['@', '@0', '0']
>>> test.sort()
>>> test
['0', '@', '@0']
```

Comment: Can you please convert this code into java? thanks

Comment: It's simple sorting, there is nothing to convert I think. But even so I don't use Java, unfortunately.

Comment: But this code is sorting the way postgres does, in python. right?

Comment: Right. But the key is `collate "C"` because default sorting in Postgres is different.