# How can we build a comparator that sorts Strings the same way that PostgreSQL does?

Tags: java, postgresql, sorting

This question is asked before as well but no one has given the correct answer to it.

[How can I build a comparator that sorts Strings the same way that PostgreSQL does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957596/how-can-i-build-a-comparator-that-sorts-strings-the-same-way-that-postgresql-doe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to build a Python comparator that sorts strings the way PostgreSQL does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063782/how-to-build-a-python-comparator-that-sorts-strings-the-way-postgresql-does?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Although the second link has the accepted answer but if anyone think that the accepted answer is correct in the second link, can they convert that code to java. My query is that i have an arraylist of strings and i want to sort it the way postgres does. thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/collationintro.html ?

Comment: I'm new at java, there isn't much I can do about it. if you provide a solution I would be grateful @DavidConrad

Comment: Depending on what your strings are, `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` might be all you need, or some settings of [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html) might suffice. Otherwise, you probably won't get PostgreSQL and Java to perfectly agree. But it really depends on what your data is.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that, because PostgreSQL uses the C library's collations (or the ones from the ICU library), while Java uses different collations.

You can have an English or Greek collation in both Java and PostgreSQL, but very likely they won't be 100% identical in both systems.

Python is a different affair, because it is implemented in C.